# Advice on setting up Rails model with multiple relations (belongs_to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, has-many-through

About to make a design decision and looking for a little validation or advice on the "Rails way" before proceeding.

Summary:

- **Users** create **Posts**
- Posts can include (one or more) **Photos**
- Posts can be (optionally) related to an **Event**
- In turn Photos from a Post are also related to said Event

One requirement, among others, would be to easily display all Photos from a given Event. Another would be showing all Photos submitted by a given User.

I originally assumed:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
...
end
```

But I'm having trouble building all the relationships in the Post controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login_required, :except => [:index, :show]

  def create
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.create(params[:post])
    # how/where to assign Event?
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

I can loop through and `build` each `:photo` param in the Post model...but not sure how/where to assign the `event_id`? Which makes me wonder if maybe there's a better approach?

Perhaps I should be exploring `has_many :through` relationships where:

User `has_many :photos, :through => :posts`

Event `has_many :photos, :through => :posts`

In a nutshell, **should I be storing the user_id & event_id in every Photo to make it easier to grab them as needed?** If so, how best to assign the associations? Or, will this become hard to maintain and thus generally frowned upon and I should use a `has_many :through` approach?

Comment: `has_many :photos, :through => :posts` is fine

Comment: ok, but what if in the future there's a mechanism (as there might be) for uploading multiple Photos related to an Event but not `:through` a Post...wouldn't `event_id` have to be hardwired (belongs_to) in each Photo? Cross that bridge when we get to it, or build in that consideration now?